# Unable to connect to FTP server from another computer with FileZilla

Tags: ftp, iis, filezilla

I created an FTP server on my local Windows 7 machine with IIS.

I can connect to the server with the machine on which I created the server, but I can't connect to the server with my laptop which is in the same local network as the machine with FTP server on it.

I configured passive mode in FileZilla and port forwarding on the router.

But the problem is always the same:

> Connection timed out

Any ideas?

Comment: Any software firewalls on the machine? Have you checked IIS is listening for all IP's? Port forwarding is not necessary within the same local network.

Comment: Yes it was the firewall problem. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The connection is most probably blocked by the Windows firewall.

While the Windows firewall is automatically configured with rules for the ports 21, 990 and 1024-65535, when IIS FTP server is installed, the rules are not enabled initially.

To enable or change the rules, go to *Control Panel > System and Security > Windows Firewall > Advanced Settings > Inbound Rules* and locate three "FTP server" rules. If the rules are not enabled, click on *Actions > Enable Rule*.

For details, see my guide for [Installing a secure FTP server on Windows using IIS](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_ftps_server).

Comment: If I understand right. FTP uses port 21 for connection and other ports in my case ports 50000 - 51000 for data transfer. Am I right?

Comment: That's correct. See my article on [FTP connection modes](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/ftp_modes) for details.